# Como usar a referencia de um arquivo de um barrel na mesma pasta com Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou tendo problemas em fazer a referência de arquivos que estão na mesma pasta quando trabalhando com um arquivo do tipo barrel no meu projeto é em Angular (versão: ^4.0.0). Meu problema é o seguinte, vejam a estrutura de arquivos e diretórios abaixo:

```
|-app
   |-index.ts
   |-app.module.ts
   |-app.routes.ts
   |-app.component.ts 
   |-foo
      |-index.ts
      |-foo.module.ts
      |-foo.routes.ts
      |-foo.component.ts
```

os dois arquivos do tipo index, contém uma estrutura simples de arquivos "barrel", como mostra aqui:

**app/index.ts**

```
export * from './app.module';
export * from './app.routes';
export * from './app.component';
```

**app/foo/index.ts**

```
export * from './foo.module';
export * from './foo.routes';
export * from './foo.component';
```

Meu problema é, quando estou em qualquer arquivo dentro do diretório `app`, consigo chamar uma referência do barrel de foo, assim:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FooRoutes, FooComponent } from './foo' // -> vai reconhecer o barrel
...
```

Mas se eu dentro do diretório `app/foo` tentar buscar um arquivo existente no próprio barrel dele da erro, diz que não foi possível encontrar o elemento (retorna `undefined`). Serial algo como:

**foo.module.ts**

```
import { FooComponent } from '../foo' // -> não acha
import { FooComponent } from '..' // -> não acha
import { FooComponent } from 'foo' // -> não acha
//wtf???
...
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: `import { FooComponent } from './foo'` também não funciona?

Comment: Acho que cria uma dependence circular importar do barrel de um arquivo que tbm esta declarado no barrel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução era a forma que eu estava declarando a importação porque eu deveria usar a mesma lógica para navegação entre pastas onde `.` representa que estou buscando algo no mesmo diretório e `..` no diretório anterior. Ficaria assim então:

```js
import { FooComponent } from '.'; // funciona
import { FooComponent } from './index'; // também funciona
```